# Center Kendo Map between markers

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-map

Is there any way to center map at the center between markers? Making its center between markers, talking into account that markers is loaded from remote `dataSource`?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done based on the example here found here:  http://www.kendoui.io/kendo-ui/dataviz/map/how-to/zoom-on-area.html

The code is as follows

```
<button id="center">Center on markers</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var markers = [
    {"latlng":[30.2675,-97.7409], "name": "Zevo Toys"},
    {"latlng": [30.2707,-97.7490],"name": "Foo Bars"},
    {"latlng": [30.2705,-97.7409],"name": "Mainway Toys"},
    {"latlng": [30.2686,-97.7494], "name": "Acme Toys"}];

    $("#map").kendoMap({
        layers: [{
            type: "tile",
            urlTemplate: "http://#= subdomain #.tile.openstreetmap.org/#= zoom #/#= x #/#= y #.png",
            subdomains: ["a", "b", "c"],
            attribution: "© <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap contributors</a>."
        }, {
            type: "marker",
            dataSource: {
                data: markers
            },
            locationField: "latlng",
            titleField: "name"
        }]
    });

    function centerMap() {
        var map = $("#map").getKendoMap();
        var layer = map.layers[1];
        var markers = layer.items;
        var extent;

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var loc = markers[i].location();

            if (!extent) {
                extent = new kendo.dataviz.map.Extent(loc, loc);
            } else {
                extent.include(loc);
            }
        }

        map.extent(extent);
    }

    $("#center").click(centerMap);
</script>
```

Comment: It is pretty disheartening to have valid answers down voted.  It seems like this as a comment would suffice.  Anyway I updated the answer with the code as requested.